# C++, Additional characters in string declaration

Tags: c++, string

I use Visual Studio 2015.
There is a simple code

```
char blablabla[] = "‭ABCDEFGH";

int main()
{
    int a = sizeof(blablabla);
    return 0;
}
```

Debugger shows that blablabla has "?ABCDEFGH" and a is 10.
What does this question mark doing here?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the string from somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unicode character of `\u202D` in your array that can not be represented in the current code page. Hence the displayed `?` character.

Comment: I have opened the main.cpp with hex editor. It is not in UNICODE but it has some weird symbols in before the A letter.

Comment: "â€­ABCDEFGH"  this is how string looks in the hex editor

Comment: @zulunation so it seems you've found the answer.

Comment: But what a hell this symbol is doing in the string declaration?

Comment: @zulunation you probably didn't type that text but you copy/pasted it from somewhere, and that u202d comes from there for whatever reason.

Comment: I have understood what happened. I have copyied the string from another source. When i found that there is a problem i started deleting the string, BUT did not delete the first quote, so the UNICODE symbol remained.